# Animation while changing the content mode for fixed view size

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimageview, contentmode

I am developing an iPhone application. I have an UIImageView whose size is fixed to 320x480. Initially contentmode is set to AspectFit. When I change the content mode to Aspect Fill, I would like to show the animation (Drawing frame of the image changes, UIImageView frame being fixed). How do I do this?